Flutter. Animate an image by pixel
I need to display an image (sort of pixel array) pixel by pixel starting from left down corner moving right, like a snake, with a little delay (0.1 second for example).

@high That timing is probably slow but the question is still a valid one. You should provide more details about what you've tried though, maybe even a code sample. Simply asking someone to implement this for you is not really what stackoverflow is for.

A possible option would be to use a ClipPath and animate it such that you're clipping everything but the pixels you want to show on each tick of the animation.  If that doesn't work for you, then it'd for sure be possible (although more complicated) with a shader.
